# Highlight a row in list view depending on column value

Tags: laravel-backpack

Using Backpack for Laravel version 4, is there a way to set a css class on a row in list view if a field on the model contains a particular value? I know the ability exists in the DataTables api, but can't think of a way to make it happen in BP4L. Thanks.

Comment: In Backpack 4.1 you can set a class on a _table cell_, but not row. See details here - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/release-notes#new-columns-feature-wrapper

Comment: I guess you can also place a class on the row with JS... Though it's not exactly a pretty solution. You can change the list.js file to check for contents after DataTables refresh, and if you find that value you can add the class to the row... Sorry David I'm afraid this is one of those things that look simple but are not, due to the way Backpack + DataTables are bound together.